# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS only displays a purple screen even after login

Tags: graphics

I wanted to upgrade from  Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 but I kept getting errors. I then run this upgrade command 'sudo apt-get upgrade -y'. After almost an hour of downloading and unpacking the packages, it froze that I had to force shutdown manually. When I tried to turn it on, i was able to login but the purple screen covers everything. Any help?

Comment: Can you get to a terminal prompt, like with Ctrl+alt+f2 maybe? From there I might try running apt to update again maybe.

Comment: IF I open the terminal it always goes back to the login screen